# Dynamodb boto3 conditional update

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am updating a counter in dynamodb and it works fine, but I would also like to do an additional update based on the value.

```
                response=table.update_item(
                    Key={
                        "record_key":record_key_val,
                        "record_type":f"REPROC|{assignment_id}"
                        },
                    UpdateExpression="""
                      SET  #attempt = #attempt + :val,
                           #last_status_code = :last_status_code
                    """,
                    ExpressionAttributeNames={
                        "#attempt": "attempt",
                        "#last_status_code" : "last_status_code"
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues={
                            ":val": 1,
                            ":last_status_code": last_status_code
                    },
                    ReturnValues='UPDATED_NEW',
                )
```

BUT I would like to add this logic in the update too

I have attribute "status" with value RETRY and would like to update it to EXPIRE after attempt > 10.

So what I think I need is ExpressionAttributeValues to have conditional logic. Can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont be able to implement that type of query logic in a single call to `update_item`.

What you *can* do is specify a [ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.ConditionalExamples) that prevents your `attempt` field from being incremented past 10.

```
table.update_item (
  // your update code 
  ConditionExpession = "#attempt <= 10"
)
```

Otherwise, you could take advantage of the `ReturnValues` that come from your update call, which will tell you the new value of the `attempt` attribute.  Your application can conditionally issue another update call to set the `status` field if the value of `attempt` equals 10.